# How to call Java methods & instantiate Java objects from Haskell easily?

Tags: java, haskell

I've found this library: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/java-bridge

Which, according to the author, supports 3 levels of binding to Java from Haskell. The [mid level interface](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/java-bridge-0.20130606.3/docs/Foreign-Java.html) works quite well, as advertised. As I am using it, though, it starts to get repetitive and boring to write the glue code as it is little more than matching up class, method, and type names in specific ways. [Here are some examples of using the mid level interface](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/java-bridge-0.20130606.3/src/examples/).

As far as I understand, the [high level interface](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/java-bridge-0.20130606.3/docs/Foreign-Java-Bindings.html) is supposed to work by automatically writing this glue code.
So I am trying to make that work without much success yet:

```
import Foreign.Java
import Foreign.Java.Bindings
import Data.Map as Map

main = runJava $ do
  jClasses <- reflectJavaClasses ["java.sql.DriverManager"]
  let info = Map.fromList [("java.sql.DriverManager", jClasses !! 0)]
  io $ putStrLn $ printJavaClassModule (jClasses !! 0) "DriverManager" info
  io $ putStrLn $ printJavaPackageModule "DriverManager" "DriverManager" info jClasses
  io $ putStrLn $ printJavaClassBootfile (jClasses !! 0) "DriverManager" info
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Preprocessing executable 'exp-java' for exp-java-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, dist/build/exp-java/exp-java-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/exp-java/exp-java ...
{-# LANGUAGE Haskell2010 #-}
-- | Class @java.sql.DriverManager@
module DriverManager (
    -- * Methods
deregisterDriver,    
equals,    
getClass,    
getConnection,    
getConnection',    
getConnection'',    
getDriver,    
getDrivers,    
getLogStream,    
getLogWriter,    
getLoginTimeout,    
hashCode,    
notify,    
notifyAll,    
println,    
registerDriver,    
setLogStream,    
setLogWriter,    
setLoginTimeout,    
toString,    
wait,    
wait',    
wait'',    
    -- * Information about this class.
    info'
) where
import qualified Foreign.Java as JNI
import Foreign.Java ((-->))
import qualified Prelude as Prelude
import Prelude ((.), ($), (>>=), (>>), return)
import qualified Foreign.Java.Bindings.Support as JNIS
import Data.Functor ((<$>))


exp-java: classModImports in Foreign.Java.Bindings.Java2Haskell - class definition not found
```

#### Questions

1. <strike>Any ideas what might cause this to say `classModImports in Foreign.Java.Bindings.Java2Haskell - class definition not found`?</strike> See edit below. It seems using `findJavaClasses` was required to get past this error.
2. Am I using this differently than it was intended?
3. Are there any examples of the intended and working usage of the high level API that I can look at?
4. Is there any other way (e.g. different library) with which I could (also/more easily) achieve an easy-to-use interfacing to Java from Haskell?

#### Edit (2015-12-28 11:42 UTC)

I managed to get a bit further, not fully working yet:

```
import Foreign.Java
import Foreign.Java.Bindings
import Data.Map as Map

main = runJava $ do
  let target = "java.sql.DriverManager"
  deps <- findJavaClasses 21 [target]
  jClasses <- reflectJavaClasses deps
  let jClassesMap = Map.fromList $ zip deps jClasses
  let l = flip Map.lookup
  let (Just targetJClass) = jClassesMap `l` target
  io $ putStrLn $ printJavaClassModule targetJClass "DriverManager" jClassesMap
```

Which outputs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Haskell2010 #-}
-- | Class @java.sql.DriverManager@
module DriverManager (
    -- * Methods
deregisterDriver,
equals,
getClass,
getConnection,
getConnection',
getConnection'',
getDriver,
getDrivers,
getLogStream,
getLogWriter,
getLoginTimeout,
hashCode,
notify,
notifyAll,
println,
registerDriver,
setLogStream,
setLogWriter,
setLoginTimeout,
toString,
wait,
wait',
wait'',
    -- * Information about this class.
    info'
) where
import qualified Foreign.Java as JNI
import Foreign.Java ((-->))
import qualified Prelude as Prelude
import Prelude ((.), ($), (>>=), (>>), return)
import qualified Foreign.Java.Bindings.Support as JNIS
import Data.Functor ((<$>))


import qualified

info' = "DriverManager"

-- | @static synchronized deregisterDriver(java.sql.Driver) -> void@
deregisterDriver :: ( v1, JNIS.VoidResult void) => v1 -> JNI.Java void
deregisterDriver a1 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "deregisterDriver" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.sql.Driver" --> JNI.void
    a1' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a1
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method a1'
    JNIS.toVoidResult result
-- | @virtual equals(java.lang.Object) -> boolean@
equals :: (JNIS.BooleanResult boolean,  this,  v1) => this -> v1 -> JNI.Java boolean
equals this a1 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getMethod` "equals" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.lang.Object" --> JNI.boolean
    this' <- JNI.asObject this
    a1' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a1
    result <- JNI.callMethodE method this' a1'
    JNIS.toBooleanResult result
-- | @virtual native final getClass() -> java.lang.Class@
getClass :: ( this, JNIS.ObjectResult (object (' v2))) => this -> JNI.Java (object (' v2))
getClass this = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getMethod` "getClass" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.lang.Class"
    this' <- JNI.asObject this
    result <- JNI.callMethodE method this'
    JNIS.toObjectResult result
-- | @static getConnection(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) -> java.sql.Connection@
getConnection :: ( v1,  v2,  v3, JNIS.ObjectResult (object ')) => v1 -> v2 -> v3 -> JNI.Java (object ')
getConnection a1 a2 a3 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "getConnection" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.lang.String" --> JNI.object "java.lang.String" --> JNI.object "java.lang.String" --> JNI.object "java.sql.Connection"
    a1' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a1
    a2' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a2
    a3' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a3
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method a1' a2' a3'
    JNIS.toObjectResult result
-- | @static getConnection(java.lang.String, java.util.Properties) -> java.sql.Connection@
getConnection' :: ( v1,  v2, JNIS.ObjectResult (object ')) => v1 -> v2 -> JNI.Java (object ')
getConnection' a1 a2 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "getConnection" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.lang.String" --> JNI.object "java.util.Properties" --> JNI.object "java.sql.Connection"
    a1' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a1
    a2' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a2
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method a1' a2'
    JNIS.toObjectResult result
-- | @static getConnection(java.lang.String) -> java.sql.Connection@
getConnection'' :: ( v1, JNIS.ObjectResult (object ')) => v1 -> JNI.Java (object ')
getConnection'' a1 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "getConnection" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.lang.String" --> JNI.object "java.sql.Connection"
    a1' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a1
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method a1'
    JNIS.toObjectResult result
-- | @static getDriver(java.lang.String) -> java.sql.Driver@
getDriver :: ( v1, JNIS.ObjectResult (object ')) => v1 -> JNI.Java (object ')
getDriver a1 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "getDriver" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.lang.String" --> JNI.object "java.sql.Driver"
    a1' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a1
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method a1'
    JNIS.toObjectResult result
-- | @static getDrivers() -> java.util.Enumeration@
getDrivers :: (JNIS.ObjectResult (object (' v2))) => JNI.Java (object (' v2))
getDrivers = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "getDrivers" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.util.Enumeration"
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method
    JNIS.toObjectResult result
-- | @static getLogStream() -> java.io.PrintStream@
getLogStream :: (JNIS.ObjectResult (object ')) => JNI.Java (object ')
getLogStream = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "getLogStream" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.io.PrintStream"
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method
    JNIS.toObjectResult result
-- | @static getLogWriter() -> java.io.PrintWriter@
getLogWriter :: (JNIS.ObjectResult (object ')) => JNI.Java (object ')
getLogWriter = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "getLogWriter" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.io.PrintWriter"
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method
    JNIS.toObjectResult result
-- | @static getLoginTimeout() -> int@
getLoginTimeout :: (JNIS.IntResult int) => JNI.Java int
getLoginTimeout = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "getLoginTimeout" JNI.::= JNI.int
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method
    JNIS.toIntResult result
-- | @virtual native hashCode() -> int@
hashCode :: (JNIS.IntResult int,  this) => this -> JNI.Java int
hashCode this = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getMethod` "hashCode" JNI.::= JNI.int
    this' <- JNI.asObject this
    result <- JNI.callMethodE method this'
    JNIS.toIntResult result
-- | @virtual native final notify() -> void@
notify :: ( this, JNIS.VoidResult void) => this -> JNI.Java void
notify this = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getMethod` "notify" JNI.::= JNI.void
    this' <- JNI.asObject this
    result <- JNI.callMethodE method this'
    JNIS.toVoidResult result
-- | @virtual native final notifyAll() -> void@
notifyAll :: ( this, JNIS.VoidResult void) => this -> JNI.Java void
notifyAll this = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getMethod` "notifyAll" JNI.::= JNI.void
    this' <- JNI.asObject this
    result <- JNI.callMethodE method this'
    JNIS.toVoidResult result
-- | @static println(java.lang.String) -> void@
println :: ( v1, JNIS.VoidResult void) => v1 -> JNI.Java void
println a1 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "println" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.lang.String" --> JNI.void
    a1' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a1
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method a1'
    JNIS.toVoidResult result
-- | @static synchronized registerDriver(java.sql.Driver) -> void@
registerDriver :: ( v1, JNIS.VoidResult void) => v1 -> JNI.Java void
registerDriver a1 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "registerDriver" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.sql.Driver" --> JNI.void
    a1' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a1
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method a1'
    JNIS.toVoidResult result
-- | @static setLogStream(java.io.PrintStream) -> void@
setLogStream :: ( v1, JNIS.VoidResult void) => v1 -> JNI.Java void
setLogStream a1 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "setLogStream" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.io.PrintStream" --> JNI.void
    a1' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a1
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method a1'
    JNIS.toVoidResult result
-- | @static setLogWriter(java.io.PrintWriter) -> void@
setLogWriter :: ( v1, JNIS.VoidResult void) => v1 -> JNI.Java void
setLogWriter a1 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "setLogWriter" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.io.PrintWriter" --> JNI.void
    a1' <- Prelude.Just <$> JNI.asObject a1
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method a1'
    JNIS.toVoidResult result
-- | @static setLoginTimeout(int) -> void@
setLoginTimeout :: (JNIS.JInt v1, JNIS.VoidResult void) => v1 -> JNI.Java void
setLoginTimeout a1 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getStaticMethod` "setLoginTimeout" JNI.::= JNI.int --> JNI.void
    a1' <- JNIS.toInt a1
    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method a1'
    JNIS.toVoidResult result
-- | @virtual toString() -> java.lang.String@
toString :: ( this, JNIS.ObjectResult (object ')) => this -> JNI.Java (object ')
toString this = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getMethod` "toString" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.lang.String"
    this' <- JNI.asObject this
    result <- JNI.callMethodE method this'
    JNIS.toObjectResult result
-- | @virtual final wait(long, int) -> void@
wait :: ( this, JNIS.JLong v1, JNIS.JInt v2, JNIS.VoidResult void) => this -> v1 -> v2 -> JNI.Java void
wait this a1 a2 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getMethod` "wait" JNI.::= JNI.long --> JNI.int --> JNI.void
    this' <- JNI.asObject this
    a1' <- JNIS.toLong a1
    a2' <- JNIS.toInt a2
    result <- JNI.callMethodE method this' a1' a2'
    JNIS.toVoidResult result
-- | @virtual native final wait(long) -> void@
wait' :: ( this, JNIS.JLong v1, JNIS.VoidResult void) => this -> v1 -> JNI.Java void
wait' this a1 = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getMethod` "wait" JNI.::= JNI.long --> JNI.void
    this' <- JNI.asObject this
    a1' <- JNIS.toLong a1
    result <- JNI.callMethodE method this' a1'
    JNIS.toVoidResult result
-- | @virtual final wait() -> void@
wait'' :: ( this, JNIS.VoidResult void) => this -> JNI.Java void
wait'' this = do
    (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager"
    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz `JNI.getMethod` "wait" JNI.::= JNI.void
    this' <- JNI.asObject this
    result <- JNI.callMethodE method this'
    JNIS.toVoidResult result
```

This is rather close now, however this won't compile with my GHC 7.8.4, even if I try to patch up the output source by hand.

1. There is an empty `import qualified` at the top, resulting in a syntax error. So I tried disabling that by commenting it out.
2. Then there were quite a few error messages pointing to various bits of the type declarations, so I commented those out too, hoping GHC might infer something sensible in their place. At least until I am just trying to make it work.
3. Then I get this error:

   ```
   Preprocessing executable 'exp-java' for exp-java-0.1.0.0...
   [1 of 2] Compiling DriverManager    ( DriverManager.hs, dist/build/exp-java/exp-java-tmp/DriverManager.o )

   DriverManager.hs:109:5:
       No instance for (JNIS.ObjectResult b3)
         arising from a use of ‘JNIS.toObjectResult’
       The type variable ‘b3’ is ambiguous
       Relevant bindings include
         getDrivers :: JNI.Java b3 (bound at DriverManager.hs:105:1)
       Note: there are several potential instances:
         instance JNIS.UnsafeCast a =>
                  JNIS.ObjectResult (Prelude.Either JNI.JThrowable (Prelude.Maybe a))
           -- Defined in ‘Foreign.Java.Bindings.Support’
         instance JNIS.UnsafeCast a =>
                  JNIS.ObjectResult (Prelude.Either (Prelude.Maybe JNI.JThrowable) a)
           -- Defined in ‘Foreign.Java.Bindings.Support’
         instance JNIS.UnsafeCast a => JNIS.ObjectResult (Prelude.Maybe a)
           -- Defined in ‘Foreign.Java.Bindings.Support’
         ...plus two others
       In a stmt of a 'do' block: JNIS.toObjectResult result
       In the expression:
         do { (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass "java.sql.DriverManager";
              (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz
                                       `JNI.getStaticMethod`
                                         "getDrivers" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.util.Enumeration";
              result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method;
              JNIS.toObjectResult result }
       In an equation for ‘getDrivers’:
           getDrivers
             = do { (Prelude.Just clazz) <- JNI.getClass
                                              "java.sql.DriverManager";
                    (Prelude.Just method) <- clazz
                                             `JNI.getStaticMethod`
                                               "getDrivers" JNI.::= JNI.object "java.util.Enumeration";
                    result <- JNI.callStaticMethodE method;
                    .... }
   ```

Which I am not yet sure how to resolve. Any ideas?

My questions 2..4 at the end of my original question, just before this edit, still stand.

Comment: Something is seriously broken here... most of these types don't make sense `wait'' :: ( this, JNIS.VoidResult void) => this -> JNI.Java void` is not well kinded (`this :: Constraint` and `this :: *`). Then the function in question `getDrivers :: (JNIS.ObjectResult (object (' v2))) => JNI.Java (object (' v2))` shouldn't even parse - `' v2` would be invalid. Perhaps try to delete the type signatures altogether and see if GHC can infer the types.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried, deleted all the type signatures by commenting them out in step 2 of my *edit*, and that lead me to step 3.